# SQL Show 0 count in child table if no rows exist for Month and Year

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have two tables Distributors and Orders. I want to get the order counts for each month (INCLUDING 0 counts)  I am Grouping by CustId Month and Year. 
NOTE : The client is using SQL 2000 :(

This is what I want

```
DistID   Month   Year   Orders
------------------------------
1        1       2012     4
1        2       2012     13
1        3       2012     5
2        1       2012     3
2        2       2012     0
2        3       2012     0
3        1       2012     8
3        2       2012     0
3        3       2012     3
4        1       2012     1
4        2       2012     0
4        3       2012     1
5        1       2012     6
5        2       2012     6
5        3       2012     0
```

This is what I get

```
DistID   Month   Year   Orders
------------------------------
1        1       2012     4
1        2       2012     13
1        3       2012     5
2        1       2012     3
3        1       2012     8
3        3       2012     3
4        1       2012     1
4        3       2012     1
5        1       2012     6
5        2       2012     6
```

I know why.  Its because there isnt a row in the Orders table for certain months.  Is there a way to put a count of 0 if there arent any rows in the Orders table for that month and year?

Here is what I have so far

```
SELECT 
D.DistID,
DATEPART(MONTH, Order_Date) AS [Month],
DATEPART(YEAR, Order_Date) AS [Year],
SUM(Total_PV) AS TotalPV,
COUNT(D.DistId) AS Orders

FROM Distributor D
LEFT OUTER JOIN Order O ON D.DistID = O.Distributor_ID                                           
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, Order_Date) > 2005
GROUP BY DistID, DATEPART(MONTH, Order_Date), DATEPART(YEAR, Order_Date)
```

Thanks for any input

Answer (score 1):

You could create a table containing all months and years, like:

```
create table MonthList(year int, month int);
```

If you fill it with all available years, you can then `left join`:

```
select  o.distributor_id
,       ml.month
,       ml.year
,       sum(o.total_pv) as totalpv
,       count(d.distid) as orders
from    monthlist ml
left join 
        [order] o 
on      datepart(year, o.order_date) = ml.year
        and datepart(month, o.order_date) = ml.month
where   ml.year > 2005
group by 
        o.distributor_id
,       ml.month
,       ml.year
```

There is no need to join in `Distributor` if you don't use columns from that table.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yeah I would need distributor because I need to account for every distributor in the table. Hence the 0 orders.  :)  Any further thoughts?  This is bugging the heck out of me.

Comment: I thought this would be pretty straight forward for a SQL guy. Might this be better suited for a SQL Forum?  Thanks!